# making jar file of a test project in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created a test suite (making a main file and calling other test cases that I like to run) .Now is it possible to make a jar file of test suite that i have made so that just by clicking on the jar i can forcefully start the test .Also is it possible to create c config value outside jar.I am using java programming language.

Help plz.

Comment: Can you plz share your code how u have written test suits.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using eclipse as an ide you can create a jar file very easily.

```
Right click on project.
Go To Export.
Select Jar or Runnable Jar as per your use click on next.
Specify the main file name.
Click on Finish.
```

Comment: Thanks abhi for immediate response

Answer (score 2):

Before doing above steps. i mean

```
Right click on project.
Go To Export.
.
.
.
.....on Finish
```

- **Clean the project** to avoid “**duplicate entry**” error when exporting Java project to JAR with Eclipse.
- Enable **Auto Refresh** in Preferences - General - Workspace - Refresh Automatically (called Refresh using native hooks or polling in newer builds)

  - Or Just right click on the project and click **Refresh**.

    to avoid “**resource is out of sync with the filesystem**” error.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project.
Go To Export.
Select Jar or Runnable Jar as per your use click on next.
Specify the main file name.
Click on Finish.