# How to create Executable file for webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Junit4 for my web driver framework.
I run all my test using test suite.
Can someone Please help me to create executable file for test suite so that manual testers can run it at their end.
I have not used main function.All my tests are written in junit that has been merged into a test suite.

Comment: Check this link if it can help you to make a jar file. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410242/making-jar-file-of-a-test-project-in-selenium-web-driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410242/making-jar-file-of-a-test-project-in-selenium-web-driver)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a main function. Maybe some classes with main function for each different execution.
If you are using Eclipse IDE:

1st- Right click on project > Run As... > Run configuration... > Java Aplication > New

Then create your configuration.

2nd- Right click on project > Export... > Runnable JAR File

Choose configuration and destination.

To run your .jar file:   `java -jar yourJar.jar`

If you need parameters on your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
```

Use like this  arg[0], arg[1], ...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to call setup method of test class from main function

Comment: If you have some testNG suites (xml files) you need (for example) to call them from your main class.

TestNG testng = new TestNG();
List<String> suites = new ArrayList<String>();
suites.add("testSuites/xxxx.xml");
testng.setTestSuites(suites);
testng.run();

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why I thought you were using TesNG... I don't work with JUnit, but I think you can use something like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm