# How Test scripts run for a specific project after completing all test scripts?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am working in automation in selenium with java and testng.I have completed all my test scripts but i don't have practical experience of working in Selenium in IT industry.
My question is how the test scripts run after completing test scripts for a specific project for regression?
1.Using Eclipse(any IDE) on regular basis or
2.Making any jar file to run on regular basis or
3.Any other means 
Please let me know what happens according to company point of view.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on companies point of view. From my work practice - we had been doing regression via selenium (Eclipse IDE), but again if the company practices continuous integration system, mostly the test must be ran by a machine, so probably then it's better to use jar which would return test results to some kind of file.

Comment: Which type of machine ...server ? how can i make a jar file to achieve desired result?

Comment: Batch or terminal scripts are okay to launch jar files. To make them, it's pretty simple ,check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410242/making-jar-file-of-a-test-project-in-selenium-web-driver

Answer (score 0):

Different companies follow different approach while doing regression testing, when using automated scripts. There is not set standards or a SOP (Standard Operating Procedure) for this. The higher level of hierarchy in the testing department (test lead etc.) has to decide, which practise will have a maximum ROI while following a specific practise.

For example, in my current organisation, I have been running a CI system, using Jenkins, which runs all the automation scripts, at a specified time on the day the regression is supposed to begin - or we trigger it and the CI takes care of the rest.

In my previous organisation, for regression purposes, we have had a dedicated system, where we would copy all the scripts, make all the necessary updates/system changes and then trigger the scripts to have the tests run.

I believe not many big companies would follow the practise of having their regression tests run individually via Eclipse IDE, since for a whole sprint (or for a whole project), there would be hundreds of test cases, involving a lot of scripts, and running them via Eclipse, would make them pretty boring and time consuming as well. Plus every single test script run would generate a separate report, which would be too complex to store and debug in case of any failure.

However, as I said, this depends entirely on how the company sees the ROI and effort to be made for this.